# Trying to copy folder into AWS EC2 instance: Getting no directory found?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, scp

So I am trying to SSH into ec2 instance and copy folder from my desktop into instance.

Command Typed: `scp -i -r prac1.pem SocialTrends ubuntu@[ec2-54-1....amazonaws.com]:socialtrendsApp/app`

Error: **Warning: Identity file -r not accessible: No such file or directory**

I am typing this command from `~/SocialTrends` directory which is what I am trying to copy. This folder has code files and the `prac1.pem file` already

**What am I doing wrong please help?!**

Comment: You're command should look like `scp -i prac1.pem -r SocialTrends ubuntu@[ec2-54-1....amazonaws.com]:socialtrendsApp/app`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have placed the command line option `-r` in between `-i` and `prac1.pem`. Move it to be after `prac1.pem`

Comment: OMG yes, this was painful.

Comment: We all do that from time to time. That is how we build our debugging skills.

Comment: Does it retain the folder structure ?

Comment: @SWastikThapaliya - Post a new quest instead of using the comment section. Yes, the -r means recursive which copies the directory structure.